# Cannot add Firestore to Server

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, server, firebase-admin

I am working on a server project where I want to user firebase firestore dependecies.

I use the firebase-admin but when I try to add firestore sdk it says that it could not find it, and yes when I looked at that site there where nothing about firestore package.

my build.grade:

```
plugins {
id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
// Firebase Admin SDK dependency
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    
    // Declare the dependency for the Cloud Firestore library
    // When NOT using the BoM, you must specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.3'
    
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.9"

}
test {
useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

The error:

```
server:main: Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.3.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/24.4.3/firebase-firestore-24.4.3.pom
  If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
  Required by:
  project :

Possible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html%60
```

I tried to look at the sites that the error code gave me but I couldnt perform anything since I dont know whether I can do this with firestore or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need `com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore` library to access `Firestore` from your server project. `google-cloud-firestore` is a dependency of `firebase-admin` ([ref](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/95e542790e1b22a26258a10f7edff3a5a29c86d4/pom.xml#L428)) and should install it as a dependency when you add Firebase Admin Java SDK to your project (unless you exclude it in your build file).

Remove the line `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.3'` from your build.gradle and access Firestore through Firebase Admin SDK. You can refer to the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#java_1) for code samples.